# handling page up in single page subfile

Tags: ibm-midrange

i am unable to handle page up option in single page sub file ....dont know how to go back to the previous rrn so that previous page can be displayed ....

Comment: Can you provide some more detail?

Comment: actually i am not able to haldle the rrn so that i can retrieve previous record when i press page up ...what logic should i use to load previous records in single page subfile...

Comment: Do you mean the RRN of the data file you're using to populate the subfile or the RRN of the subfile records?

Answer (score 1):

The required logic is:

- Check the indicator of the rolldown key
- If that indicator is true, then clear your subfile
- Your file pointer must go 13 (of whatever) rows back. Do that with readb, setll, chain and recordnumber, or something else (that is up to you)
- Rebuild your subfile

DON'T FORGET to reset your subfile number!!!!!!!!!!!

For small files, building the complete subfile at once and let the iSeries do the handling is much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest might be to use `FETCH NEXT FOR sflRows...` when paging forward and `FETCH RELATIVE previousSflRows FOR sflRows...` when paging backwards. You'll set the sflRows variable to be the number of subfile rows you have on a single page. And set the previousSflRows to be twice that number, but make it negative.

So, with SFLPAG=10, you can `FETCH` 10 rows at a time going forward. After the first page, the file position will be at row 11. After page 2, it'll be at 21; and after page 3, at 31.

At that time, if the user wants to go back a page, the prevSflRows value will cause that `FETCH` to read the rows beginning at (31 - 20) or file position 11. That's exactly where it was the first time page 2 of the subfile was shown.